# iOS 11 FileProvider NSFileProviderRootContainerItemIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I'm trying to developing a FileProvider Extension for iOS 11.But I run into a weird problem.

```
- (nullable NSFileProviderItem)itemForIdentifier:(NSFileProviderItemIdentifier)identifier error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

In this method,the identifier always is NSFileProviderRootContainerItemIdentifier.According to Apple's Document,this identifier supposes to be unique.

how should I implement this method?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a new NSFileProviderItem For NSFileProviderRootContainerItemIdentifier.

don't return nil,that will cause a problem when try to use Filprovider extension in other app.

Answer (score 0):

When I started writing my File Provider I thought the same as you but the root container always has the item identifier of NSFileProviderRootContainerItemIdentifier.  You must return that as the Identifier of the NSFileProviderItem that you return in that call and it must also be the ParentIdentifier of your top-level items.

Comment: I figure this out, if the item identifier is NSFileProviderRootContainerItemIdentifier,we can reture nil for this method